# SQL Server and nested SELECT:  ...Incorrect syntax near ')'?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get this error when executing my code. What does this mean? I'm using SQL Server Management Server Express.

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.

---

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime
set @start = '2012/01/02'
set @end = '2012/01/06'


SELECT  
 SUM(VCount) as [Total],
 vdate,
 (select COUNT(VIP) From (SELECT DISTINCT(VIP) FROM dbo.Visiter)) as [IP3]
FROM dbo.Visiter 
where VDate between @start and @end
GROUP BY VDate
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In SQL Server, when you use a derived table (a subquery) in the FROM clause, you must give that derived table an alias:

```
SELECT  
 SUM(VCount) as [Total],
 vdate,
 -- add an alias in the next line
 (select COUNT(VIP) From (SELECT DISTINCT(VIP) FROM dbo.Visiter) AS a) as [IP3]
FROM dbo.Visiter 
where VDate between @start and @end
GROUP BY VDate
```

reference: [FROM clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

I think this

```
(select COUNT(VIP) From (SELECT DISTINCT(VIP) FROM dbo.Visiter)) as [IP3]
```

is better to transform to

```
(select COUNT(DISTINCT VIP) FROM dbo.Visiter) as [IP3]
```

AFAIK, MySQL at least says `Every derived table must have its own alias` so, your sub-query shoulda look like

```
(select COUNT(v) From (SELECT DISTINCT(VIP) AS v FROM dbo.Visiter) AS tmp1) as [IP3]
```

but the shorter - the better =)

Comment: id doing and get this :

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: i want get number of unique visitors but this get me sum all unique visitors . please help me (sorry for my weak english ;D)

Comment: @user1133937 which language do you prefer? =) and i did not understand your last question, i am sorry for that... i am a bit blunt last days =)

Comment: @user1133937 if you do want we can talk over GTalk or email for more detailed help =)

Comment: i have this table : 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/gmGdx.gif
and get this :
http://i.stack.imgur.com/YKeRR.gif
but i want this
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym42g.gif

Comment: does the column `VDate` means `the date of last visit`?

Comment: oh... you just need to select all distinct `VIP` values between `start_date` and `end_date` ;)

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VIP) FROM dbo.Visiter WHERE VDate BETWEEN @start AND @end` - try this one. Hope this will help =)

Comment: @user1133937 it should return number of different users / IPs who were visiting your website between `@start` and `@end` dates. Or i did not understand you =P